# How to pass handler in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a project which is written in react-redux. I want to pass the handler the to the child component so that I can trigger the handler from the child component.
My parent component code

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from 'src/containers/Input';

export default class AddChannelComponent extends React.Component<void, PropsType, void> {
  render() {    
       function inputHandler (value){
            console.log("value  is",value);
       }

    return (
        <div >
          <p>Type your input</p>
          <div>
            <Input inputHandler={this.inputHandler} placeholder="Search all public channels..." />
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Input is a js file which call a component InputComponent.js
Code of Input.js file is:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import InputComponent from 'src/components/InputComponent';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ 
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
});

const Input = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(InputComponent);

export default Input;
```

Now My InputComponent.js file code is:

```
import React from 'react';


export default class InputComponent extends React.Component<void, PropsType, void> {
     callHandler = event => {
          console.log("value in input",event.target.value);
          this.props.inputHandler(event.target.value)   <== Error Occur
     }
  render() {
    return (
      <input {...this.props}  onChange={this.callHandler}/>
    );
  }
}
```

this.props.inputHandler(event.target.value) gives me error that _this.props.inputHandler is not a function. How to call a parent handler in child component.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  inputHandler = (value) => {
       console.log("value  is",value);
  }    
  render() {    
   ......
```

instead

```
render() {    
   function inputHandler (value){
        console.log("value  is",value);
   }
   ......
```

write `inputHandler` function in the scope of `AddChannelComponent` class then use `this.inputHandler`

if you are using closure function (in your case) use directly `inputHandler` as

```
    <Input inputHandler={inputHandler} placeholder="Search all public channels..." />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a short anwser:
have you tried to define your `inputHandler` fn as a class method?
You try to access it by `this.inputHandler` but the fn is defined within the render method.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind you method, according to [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that method.
>
> If calling bind annoys you, there are two ways you can get around this. If you are using the experimental property initializer syntax, you can use property initializers to correctly bind callbacks

So, in your example:

```js
import React from 'react';


export default class InputComponent extends React.Component<void, PropsType, void> {
     callHandler = event => {
          console.log("value in input",event.target.value);
          this.props.inputHandler(event.target.value)   <== Error Occur
     }
  render() {
    return (
      <input {...this.props}  onChange={this.callHandler.bind(this)}/>
    );
  }
}
```